# json in variable become [object object] after ajax callback

Tags: javascript

In js I do:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function(event) {
   var saveData = dataSet[a];
   console.log(saveData);
```

That gives me various json objects in console like

```
{data: Array(48), Province/State: "Suffolk County, NY", Country/Region: "US", Lat: 40.9849, Long: -72.6151}
{data: Array(48), Province/State: "Ulster County, NY", Country/Region: "US", Lat: 41.8586, Long: -74.3118}
```

Then I do a check for something else in ajax and on success I give `saveData` as a data attribute to a button `<button data-id="'+saveThis+'">` but it gives `[object Object]`.

If I do a check in console after ajax, before to tell the button to grab that var as a data attribute, so

```
$.ajax({
 url: ajax_url,
 type: 'post',
 data: { action: 'data_savedInternal', id: saveThis },
 success: function(data) {
  console.log(saveThis);
```

I get the correct json

```
{data: Array(48), Province/State: "Suffolk County, NY", Country/Region: "US", Lat: 40.9849, Long: -72.6151}
{data: Array(48), Province/State: "Ulster County, NY", Country/Region: "US", Lat: 41.8586, Long: -74.3118}
```

Comment: @r3wt I tried to set it as a string like `savData = saveData.toString()` but yet, nothing, I tried using `JSON.parse(saveData)` but yet, nothing. So here I am asking.

Comment: could you try using Json.Strignify(saveData)

Comment: When you cast an object to a string, you get `'[object Object]'`. This is also the result of the `toString` method on `Object.prototype`. If you want it serialized out to JSON, use `JSON.stringify`. This is all **really** basic stuff.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks, really did think doing saveData.toString() would work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please convert your json to string via JSON.stringify. `<button data-id="'+JSON.stringify(saveThis)+'">`

Comment: really did think doing saveData.toString() would work. Thanks for this

Comment: Yes you were almost there by using ToString.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store objects as data attributes in the dom. but, you can save your data into an indexed array of data objects, then store the index on your data id, then use that index to access the data later.

example:

```
var globalDataStore = [];

google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function(event) {
   var saveData = dataSet[a];
   console.log(saveData);

   var index = globalDataStore.length;// the length of the array prior to push is equal to the index of your new data object after push occurs.
   globalDataStore.push(saveData);// push the data into the array

   $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_savedInternal', id: saveThis },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(saveThis);
            // now update your button with the index
            // you are not showing how you do that, so below is just pseudo code
            // pseudocode: <button data-id="'+index+'">
        }
    });

});
```

Now, when you are ready to use that data again, perhaps on click of the button, you can use the buttons data id to select your data from the global array:

```
//assume this is one of your buttons
button.onClick(e=>{
    var index = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    index = parseInt(index,10);//convert to int, because its a string from being in dom.
    var saveData = globalDataStore[index];
    console.log(saveData);
    //now do something with your data
});
```

Comment: really did think doing saveData.toString() would work. Thanks for this

Comment: @rob.m you can save it to the dom as json (like the other poster mentioned, but afaik its frowned upon and could possibly break your ui if the json contains html. you can do so with `JSON.stringify(saveData);` but i would highly recommend against doing so. i have done so before in the past as a wee noob but now a days i'd rather leave it in memory for safe keeping. if i need it to persist, there's local storage, cookies, etc